# why is modern pixijs so much slower than v3.0.0?

Tags: javascript, webgl, pixi.js, webgl2

this is bunnymark. it renders 100k sprites at 17 fps
https://pixijs.io/bunny-mark/

this is an old version of bunnymark using pixi v3. it renders 100k sprites at 165 fps (at least) https://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/bunnymark/

old pixijs v3 is oredrs of magnitude faster than modern pixijs. how can i render that fast with modern pixijs???

Comment: Hi Farzher, i just checked both and you are completly right. I noticed that the recent test has way more renders calls per frame than the v3.

Comment: the explanation with more details is here: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/discussions/8181